# Can we install Docker in D11_v2 Azure Windows 10 Enterprise machine?

Tags: azure, docker, window

I am not able to install Docker in Windows 10 Azure machine.

Machine Details - Promo D11_v2 (2 Cores, 14 GB memory)
OS - Windows 10 
Architecture - 64 bit
Hosted - Azure

Error Message - 
Unable to start: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to install Docker in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to install Docker in Windows 10?

Docker, do you mean windows container?

It is possible to install windows container on Azure VM, but we should choose VM size to **Dv3 or Ev3**, **those VM sizes support nested virtualization**.

Windows Server Containers require **Hyper-V isolation** on Windows 10 in order to provide developers with the same kernel version and configuration that will be used in production.

By the way, Dv3 and Ev3 VM size geographic availability:

[image]

More information about nested virtualization in Azure, please refer to this [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/nested-virtualization-in-azure/).

Comment: Does this work for you? Please let me know if you need more help:)